# How to get the fields from a WorkItem using a WIQL in one call to speed up?

Tags: performance, tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem, wiql

I've have the following code to get some specific WorkItems:

```
string workItemQueryString = "Select Id, State, Type From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = 'Code Review Request' And [Area Path] = 'abc' Order By [Changed Date] Desc";
var workItemQuery = new Query(workItemStore, workItemQueryString);
WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemQuery.RunQuery();
```

This code runs fast (< 1 sec). However I also want to get some extra fields like "Associated Context Type" and "Associated Context".

So I use this code get get those fields:

```
var workItemDetails = queryResults.Cast<WorkItem>().Select(workItem => new WorkItemDetail
{
    WorkItem = workItem,
    AssociatedContextType = workItem.Fields.Contains("Associated Context Type") ? workItem.Fields["Associated Context Type"].Value : null,
    AssociatedContext = workItem.Fields.Contains("Associated Context") ? workItem.Fields["Associated Context"].Value : null
}).ToList();
```

But this code runs very slow (13 to 20 seconds) which looks to me that separate queries (for each workitem?) are fired to the TFS server to get all data.

Note that when I use a **Parallel.ForEach** statement, the code breaks with an exception.

The total number of WorkItems in the WorkItemCollection is about 2800.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? I have less work items in my TFS 2015.3, and I couldn't see the code is slow. Is it slow when you run query in VS or Web Access?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
AssociatedContextType = workItem.Fields.Contains("AssociatedContextType") ? workItem.Fields["AssociatedContextType"].Value : null,
AssociatedContext = workItem.Fields.Contains("AssociatedContext") ? workItem.Fields["AssociatedContext"].Value : null
```

to:

```
AssociatedContextType = workItem.Fields.Contains("Associated Context Type") ? workItem.Fields["Associated Context Type"].Value : null,
AssociatedContext = workItem.Fields.Contains("Associated Context") ? workItem.Fields["Associated Context"].Value : null
```

Comment: Sorry, It was a copy paste error. I actually used "Associated Context Type" and "Associated Context".

Comment: I could speed it up with settings the PageSize a bit higher:          "queryResults.PageSize = 200;"